# Histogram with two variables in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with two variables:

```
DF <- data.frame(Now = as.numeric(c(1, 6, 4, 4, 5, 6)), Before = as.numeric(c(1, 6, 3, 5, 10, 10)))
```

I can easily plot both variables separately:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(Now))+
  geom_histogram()
ggplot(DF, aes(Before))+
  geom_histogram()
```

But I would like to plot both variables together, so that the change between Before and Now is easy to see. One way to do this is described in an answer here: [Plot two variables in the same histogram with ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785550/plot-two-variables-in-the-same-histogram-with-ggplot). But I would much rather have one plot with differently colored bars side-by-side. How can this be done? (Side note: if it's easier to do with `geom_bar` than `geom_histogram`, that works for me too.)

Comment: Andrew Gustar has already answered this, but it's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48591363/two-bars-next-to-each-other-using-geom-bar/48591449#48591449)

Comment: Thanks. Search didn't return that question.

Comment: Only reason I found it easily is 'cause I checked my answer history ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `DF` to long format using something like `tidyr::gather`...

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

DF %>% 
  gather(key=Type, value=Value) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Value,fill=Type)) + 
  geom_histogram(position="dodge")
```

[image]